# Erro ao compartilhar app android pelo facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk

Quero compartilhar o link da minha app android pelo facebook usando o facebook sdk com um ShareButton a aplicação do facebook inicia mas logo fecha e lança o seguinte error.

I/ERROR:: Failed to get app name.

Alguém já passou por isso e possui alguma dica?

Ah e peno facebook message eu consigo compartilhar.

Comment: Você criou o projeto no facebook developers?

Comment: Sim criei fiz tudo